# Keep state of complete application once quit

Tags: cocoa, memory, nstextview

I am having trouble keeping the state of my Mac OS X app (running on Lion) when it is closed - it currently only has an NSTextView in the window and I want to keep the state of the window size and the text that's actually in my NSTextView along with its formatting for when the application next loads up.

I was therefore wondering if anyone could give me a pointer (ha, get it - pointer?) as to how to go about keeping the state of my application so it's the same when the application is opened again once quit. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with just storing your information in the user defaults using the NSUserDefaults class, and then loading those settings back in when the application launches?

In the XIB, you can set your window to "not visible at startup". You can then implement `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in your AppDelegate, do the appropriate setup there - the final line of code in that method would be to make the app's window visible. This way you avoid any user confusion and the app will look snappy and responsive, i.e. until the app is fully loaded nothing becomes visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - I'm somewhat new to storing information within a Cocoa application and I was wondering if you knew of any tutorials/resources regarding how to actually implement this... Thanks a lot for your response - much appreciated!

Comment: Well, I personally learned about NSUserDefaults in Aaron Hillegass' book "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X". But I think Apple's documentation should be good too. Just go to the NSUserDefaults page in the Xcode documentation, and there you'll see a link to the "User Defaults Programming Topics" companion guide.